# subsonic Invalid cast from System.Int32 to System.Byte[]

Tags: vb.net, subsonic2.2

Subsonic 2.2 is throwing the error

```
subsonic Invalid cast from System.Int32 to System.Byte[]
```

When I do the following

```
        If template.Content Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox("Blank Document")
        Else
            MsgBox("Document Present")
        End If
```

"template" is a SubSonic object of which it's "content" field is of type Byte()

Why is this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SubSonic object was initialized incorrectly.

Solution

```
Dim template as New TemplateDocument(Guid.NewID()) with {.content = Nothing}
```